# SMB access mask - MAXIMUM_ALLOWED vs GENERIC_ALL

Tags: winapi, smb

According to [this web site about SMB access masks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-smb/27f99d29-7784-4684-b6dd-264e9025b286),

1. MAXIMUM_ALLOWED (0x02000000) - This value indicates that the client
   is requesting an open to the file with the highest level of access
   the client has on this file. If no access is granted for the client
   on this file, the server MUST fail the open with
   STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED.
2. GENERIC_ALL (0x10000000) - This value
   indicates a request for all the access flags that are previously
   listed, except MAXIMUM_ALLOWED and ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY.

I'd like to know what are common use cases for using these.  Specifically, if I wanted to be maximally permissive, shouldn't I use GENERIC_ALL?  And though it says in its description that it doesn't include MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, because it includes the previously mentioned access flags wouldn't GENERIC_ALL therefore also subsume MAXIMUM_ALLOWED?  I have a feeling I'm missing some important concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so technically this is a Windows question, not sure why that tag is missing. The meaning of those two values differs, but you also *should* be aware of another related concept: [GENERIC_MAPPING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-generic_mapping).

The generic mapping allows to turn generic access masks (for read, write and all) into object-type-specific access masks. As the name implies, these are specific to the object type, i.e. file, pipe, memory mapped file ("Section"), mutex ("Mutant") etc. You can use [WinObj from Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/winobj) to get a sense of the object types available in Windows. However, you just need to be *aware* that this exists and there is no need to know all the details. This becomes relevant only when you are using the ACL editor and need to do that mapping yourself, for example. Every object type basically comes with a mapping like that.

After obtaining a handle to an object, you can query `OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION` (public prototype [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_public_object_basic_information); [alternative](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/inc/api/ntobapi/object_basic_information.htm)) to see what level of *object-type-specific* access was granted.

Obtaining the handle is the part where the access check happens. This is why passing around or inheriting handles can be an issue, sometimes. So if the SD/DACL says you don't have the requested level of access or outright denies it, you won't even get a handle and instead will get to see `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`.

### The difference

Now that we have this out of the way let's discuss the difference between `GENERIC_ALL` and `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED`.

If you paid attention above, you may already see why they are semantically different.

`MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` -- as the name suggests -- requests whatever access you have available and `OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION::GrantedAccess` can tell you what that is. If you don't get a handle and instead see `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`, you simply don't have any sort of access to said object.

`GENERIC_ALL` instead requests the actual *maximum* access based on the generic mapping. And if you don't have *all* of those access types requested it will fail all the same.

So in conclusion:

- `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` will try to get you a handle with *any* access level that you can get (it *could* be the *actual* maximum, too)
- `GENERIC_ALL` will try to get you a handle specifically with **all** access types subsumed under this generic mapping ... **if any** of those **"all"** fails, you won't get a handle and instead see `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`.

If you wanted to be maximally permissive (the way I understand it) you'd want to use: `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED`, because the (still generic but more specific) `GENERIC_ALL` will fail to even get you a handle in many cases where `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` yields one.

In the best case -- given your intent -- you will be granted an access that amounts to `GENERIC_ALL` without running the risk that you don't get a handle at all.

Alternatively you could request access to the object at your *desired* access level (e.g. `GENERIC_ALL`) and have a staggered fallback to `GENERIC_WRITE` etc. and as last ditch effort try `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED`. The advantage is that with the concrete desired access masks -- *if and when you get a handle back!* -- you know the access level. With `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` you would still have to query `OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION::GrantedAccess` in order to find that out (well, or attempt an action and get `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` or `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`).